# how to test whether a set contains any sum of two other numbers in the set

Tags: java, recursion

Lets say I have numbers 7 and 43 in my `isSumAB`, and if a and b are in my `isSumAB` then of course I can have `a + b` . So what I am trying to do is have a boolean recursive function to test my array something like this if its true or not...so how can I have a boolean function that will let me do this with int a and b ?

```
int[] numbers = {10, 51,137, 464, 589 ...};

     for(int num: numbers){
                System.out.println("isSumAB()-- is " + num + " Sum of A and B in Java :" + isSumAB(num));
    }
```

something goes in this method

```
public boolean isSumAB(int a, int b){

   if ( a > b )
     return false
   else if 
        y + sum( x, y - 1 );
      return true 
      //something

}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to check if there is an element in your  array that has the same value as the sum of two other integers?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes sir!

Comment: Also confused. Is the question whether any of the numbers is the sum of two other numbers in the set, or whether any of them is the sum of two immediately preceding numbers, or whether any of them is the sum of two numbers obtained from somewhere else? Is the `numbers` array presorted into ascending order or not? Are they guaranteed to all be positive or not? Whichever you're looking for, recursion is almost certainly the wrong solution to the problem, and you're making this fifteen times harder than it needs to be. Think about how you would solve it manually, and implement that.

Comment: @keshlam it is any of the numbers is the sum of two other numbers in the set. No negative numbers, they are all positive.

Comment: OK, so what's wrong with just doing two nested loops scanning the set?

Comment: I think the question should be edited to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import  java.util.Iterator;
import  java.util.Map;
import  java.util.Set;
import  java.util.TreeMap;
/**
   <P>{@code java FindElementsThatAreSumsOfOthers}</P>
 **/
public class FindElementsThatAreSumsOfOthers  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      int[] ai = new int[]{10, 51, 137, 464, 589, 61, 452};

      //All numbers in a map, key is array-value, value is array-index
      Map<Integer,Integer> mpValIdxAll = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();

      for(int i = 0; i < ai.length; i++)  {
         mpValIdxAll.put(ai[i], i);
      }

      //Only those elements in the array that are *sums* of other elements
      //Key is array-index of sum, value is SumInfo object
      Map<Integer,SumInfo> mpValIdxSums = new TreeMap<Integer,SumInfo>();

      for(int i = 0; i < ai.length; i++)  {
         //j + 1: So we don't test the same combination twice.
         for(int j = i + 1; j < ai.length; j++)  {
            int iSum = ai[i] + ai[j];

            if(mpValIdxAll.containsKey(iSum))  {
               //The all-map contains the sum, so add it to the sum-map
               mpValIdxSums.put(mpValIdxAll.get(iSum), new SumInfo(ai[i], i, ai[j], j));
            }
         }
      }

      Set<Integer> stSumIdxs = mpValIdxSums.keySet();
      Iterator<Integer> itrSumIdxs = stSumIdxs.iterator();
      while(itrSumIdxs.hasNext())  {
         int iIdxSum = itrSumIdxs.next();
         SumInfo si = mpValIdxSums.get(iIdxSum);
         System.out.println(ai[iIdxSum] + " (element " + iIdxSum + ")  is the sum of elements " + si.iA + " (idx=" + si.iIdxA + ") and " + si.iB + " (idx=" + si.iIdxB + ")");
      }
   }
}
//The two elements that are a sum of another element
class SumInfo  {
   public final int iA;
   public final int iIdxA;
   public final int iB;
   public final int iIdxB;
   public SumInfo(int i_addendA, int i_ndexA, int i_addendB, int i_ndexB)  {
      iA = i_addendA;
      iIdxA = i_ndexA;
      iB = i_addendB;
      iIdxB = i_ndexB;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java FindElementsThatAreSumsOfOthers
589 (element 4)  is the sum of elements 137 (idx=2) and 452 (idx=6)
61 (element 5)  is the sum of elements 10 (idx=0) and 51 (idx=1)
```